# Apache não lê o Index.php do Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Bom dia galera,estou tentando instalar o Magento 2.2.x.Fiz a instalação do Apache 2.4,MySQL,PHP7.1 e suas respectivas extensooes necessarias,rodei o composer e instalou direitinho.

Porem quando entro no server apache "localhost" a pagina fica em branco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando ponho outro index para exibir as informações PHP,aparece
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu acho que posso estar errando é nas permissoes do diretorio,esta tudo 777.Ou em alguma configuração como por exemplo do php.ini.Mas não sei...

Se alguem puder ajudar eu agradeço bastante!

Answer (score 0):

entao brother...

normalmente, o index.php do Magento esta dentro da pasta "magento", certo?!

entao a URL correta seria: `localhost/magento`
ou ainda: `localhost:8080/magento`
ou entao: `127.0.0.1/magento`

sendo "magento" o nome do diretorio onde estao seus arquivos de instalacao...

vc moveu o diretorio "magento" para dentro do diretorio "www"? ou configurou o apache para puxar os arquivos de outro diretorio? as vezes acontece do erro estar nessa configuracao www.

sucesso ai.